# How do I know exactly the key of the dictionary in the private api

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I found i have to use a method in the private api,like this

> initWithFetchDictionary:(id)arg1 propertyHint:(unsigned int)arg2 photoLibrary:(id)arg3

but i don't know what the "FetchDictionary" 's Key is.
is there any way to get this?

Comment: FetchDictionary is the method call fnction

Comment: @Anbu Karthik: he means the parameter not the method name.

Comment: @warlock: No, you can't, because this is the meaning of _private_.

Comment: @macmoonshine okey..i tried to method swizzle it,but in different app,it does not work.Now i wonder how other developers use pri api,perhaps the api they use doesn't have parameter whose type is dictionary..